# proper syntax for the s command along to the addressing in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to issue this command from the bash script
`sed -e $beginning,$s/pattern/$variable/ file`

but any possible combination of quotes gives me an error, only one that works:
`sed -e "$beginning,$"'s/pattern/$variable/' file`

also not good, because it do not dereferences the variable.

Does my approach can be implemented with sed?

Comment: ` sed -e "$begining,$ s/pattern/$variable/"  file `

Comment: That, and make sure your `$variable` doesn't contain any `/`, or change the `s/pattern/replacement/` separator

Comment: @JJoao works from the shell itself but gives an error when launched from the bash script `sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: \`,'`

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to switch the quotes up. The shell can keep things straight.

```
sed -e "$beginning"',$s/pattern/'"$variable"'/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$ sed -e "$beginning,$ s/pattern/$variable/" file
```

#### Example

**file.txt:**

```
one
two
three
```

Try:

```
$ beginning=1
$ variable=ONE
$ sed -e "$beginning,$ s/one/$variable/" file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
ONE
two
three
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of quotes:

- Single quotes preserve their contents (`>` is the prompt):

  ```
  > var=blah
  > echo '$var'
  $var
  ```
- Double quotes allow for parameter expansion:

  ```
  > var=blah
  > echo "$var"
  blah
  ```

And two types of `$` sign:

- One to tell the shell that what follows is the name of a parameter to be expanded
- One that stands for "last line" in sed.

You have to combine these so

1. The shell doesn't think sed's `$` has anything to do with a parameter
2. The shell parameters still get expanded (can't be within single quotes)
3. The whole sed command is quoted.

One possibility would be

```
sed "$beginning,\$s/pattern/$variable/" file
```

The whole command is in double quotes, i.e., parameters get expanded (`$beginning` and `$variable`). To make sure the shell doesn't try to expand `$s`, which doesn't exist, the "end of line" `$` is escaped so the shell doesn't try anything funny.

Other options are

- Double quoting everything but adding a space between `$` and `s` (see [Ren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662748/3266847))
- Mixing quoting types as needed (see [Ignacio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662724/3266847))

#### Methods that don't work

```
sed '$beginning,$s/pattern/$variable/' file
```

Everything in single quotes: the shell parameters are not expanded (doesn't follow rule 2 above). `$beginning` is not a valid address, and `pattern` would be literally replaced by `$variable`.

```
sed "$beginning,$s/pattern/$variable/" file
```

Everything in double qoutes: the parameters are expanded, including `$s`, which isn't supposed to (doesn't follow rule 1 above).

Answer (score -1):

the following form worked for me from within script

```
sed $beg,$ -e s/pattern/$variable/ file
```

the same form will also work if executed from the shell

Comment: This will cause all sorts of bizarre behavior given various possible contents of your shell variables. **ALWAYS** quote your shell variables unless you have a very specific goal in mind by not doing so and fully understand all of the implications. If you don't precisely understand the terms globbing, word splitting, and file name expansion then make sure to study them before you do this and then you won't do it. See [@Ignacio's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36662724/1745001) for the correct quoting.